# Is it possible to invalidate all Google AMP cached URLs by one call?

Tags: amp-html

I have created AMP pages and it is cached successfully by google.

Now, I want to invalidate all Google AMP cached URLs in the CDN cache.

Is it possible, and if possible how can I get all cached URLs from the AMP CDN?

Answer (score 1):

You best bet is to use `update-ping` request:

https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-ping#update-ping-request

**To invalidate your pages**

You will have to hit a an `update-ping` URL for each of your pages. If the URL of your cache page is:

`https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/example.com`

then to invalidate you must hit this URL:

`https://cdn.ampproject.org/update-ping/c/s/example.com`

**To remove your pages altogether**

You will have to

1. Remove the AMP page from your server, then
2. Hit the ping URL as above

Note

- that you will have to wait at least 4 minutes
- HTTP and HTTPS URLS must be removed separately

Comment: For every page i have to call update ping request to invalidate amp cache. is there any possibility to invalidate all cached urls on single update ping call.

Comment: You can't do this with a single update-ping request. If you can get a list of all your AMP pages on your server, then you could write a script to iterate over this list, requesting the udpdate-ping URL for each AMP page

Comment: there's no way exposed by AMP cache to get this list. I meant more to get a list of your AMP URLs at your end. If you're using a CMS like wordpress you should be able to query the database directly for the URLs

Comment: thanks for information and one last doubt is when i check at my server end useragent coming as (compatible; Google-AMPHTML). what is meaning of this, is it google amp crawler user agent ???

Comment: Yes, that's the AMP cache crawler useragent:  

`"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Google-AMPHTML)"`

Comment: If i want to check Google AMP crawler is coming on to my site simply i have to check (compatible; Google-AMPHTML) contains in useragent or anyother extra checks required to detect Google AMP crawler ??? @rodders

Comment: Yes, that should be enough to identify it.